# Trying to obtain a Clean URL in GTM

Tags: javascript

Using custom JS code, I'm trying to generate a "clean URL" variable in Google Tag Manager.

The Clean URL would exclude everything after the query (?), what would be the easiest way to tackle this?

Concatenating the hostname+page path seems like a good option?

Typical URL -

```
https://www.example.com/en-gb/subscribe?utm_campaign=test&utm_source=test2&utm_medium=test3
```

Clean URL should be -

```
www.example.com/en-gb/subscribe
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a good option.

I am using the [URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) here

```js
const url = new URL("https://www.example.com/en-gb/subscribe?utm_campaign=test&utm_source=test2&utm_medium=test3")

console.log(url.hostname+url.pathname)
```